# How to make app support Samsung's popup-view?

Tags: android, user-interface, popup

A user of my app complained that he can't open the app in a popup window [(like this)](http://www.samsung.com/sa_en/support/skp/faq/1063776).

When he tries to do so, a toast saying "This app cannot be shown in popup-view" appears.

I couldn't find any documentation about this feature, specifically not about enabling it for your app. Some users seem to find this useful so I thought about enabling that for my app if that isn't to much work.

Could anyone point me to the documentation of this feature or better yet explain how to add it to an Android app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

put these lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable"
        android:value="true"/>
```

thanks to [saurabh1489](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110064/saurabh1489)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is supported by Samsung MultiWindow Framework.To make it work, you need to test the feature on the Samsung Devices which support MultiWindow functionality like Samsung Note series etc.Samsung provides MultiWindow SDK for third party developers to develop applications to support multiwindow functionality.The technical documentation regarding Multiwindow can be found here :
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000144L

Unfortunately this feature is not supported by Non-Samsung devices.